Examples of the most subordinate infinitive clauses combined in one sentence
Personally, I think it to be interesting when I find multiple infinitive clauses in a sentence.
Based of this structure: Cogitavi virum putavisse eum ambulavisse,” (I thought that the man thought than he was walking), could anybody find examples of classic litteratere when the author used multiple infinitive clauses? The infinitives themselves can be active or passive and with any combination of tense. I’m looking for 2 infinitives strung together but if more can be found that would be even better.

Here is one example from Cicero, where the passive infinitive deprehensum [esse] is embedded to the active infinitive audisse, which in turn depends on the main verb credo. Note that both subordinate clauses are Accusativus cum Infinitivo (AcI) constructions: the accusative pronoun te is the subject of audisse and P. Clodium (Appi f.) is the subject of deprehensum [esse].

P. Clodium Appi f. credo te audisse cum veste muliebri deprehensum [esse] domi C. Caesaris ... (Cic. Att. 1.12.3) 'I imagine you will have heard that P. Clodius, son of Appius, was caught dressed up as a woman in C. Caesar's house.'


Some additional examples with a 2nd level of infinitival subordination follow:

si hic ordo placere sibi decreverit te ire in exsilium, obtemperaturum te esse dicis. (Cic. Catil. 1.20) ‘If this body decides to vote for you to go into exile, you say you will obey.’


qui dixisset ita amare oportere ut si aliquando esset osurus (Cic. Amic. 59) '... who had made this remark: “We should love as if at some time we were going to hate".'

Examples with a 3rd level of infinitival subordination are more difficult to find but here is an example of this interesting type:

hominem ingeniosum, M. Antonium, aiunt solitum esse dicere 'idcirco se nullam umquam orationem scripsisse ut, si quid aliquando non opus esset ab se esse dictum, posset negare dixisse'. (Cic. Clu. 140) 'They say that that able man, Marcus Antonius, was accustomed to say “that he had never written a speech, in order that, if at any time he had said anything which was not desirable, he might be able to deny that he had said it.”

Cf. aiunt (main verb) -- solitum esse (1st level of infinitival subord.) -- dicere (2nd level of infinitival subord.) -- scripsisse (3rd level of infinitival subord.).

Thank you so much, these examples are great!
